# binding objects to a row with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some tabular data, a list of products.

```
id | name | description | options
1  | foo  | bar         | [delete]
```

now normally I just set a class on the delete button like .delete-item and do

```
$('.delete-item').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // do something/ajax etc
});
```

but with this, I am going to add some other features like inline editing of the description. Now I could bind another function like my delete one, but I am being to wonder if there is a more jquery way of doing this as I might later add product price and quantity with automatic calculation of total, it could get quite hairy.

maybe a plugin, or some sort of object?

```
$('table').productEditor();
```

does that make sense? Is there something I go and read up about this sort of thing more?

Comment: So you want to turn your table field into inputs on click??

Comment: Based on your requirements and the way you are planning to scale this tabular data, i think datatables is your way to go. check http://datatables.net.

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz - yes, but it's more than that. instead of 4-5 $(....).click() functions floating in a file, should they be in a plugin / class?

Comment: @Raghu - thanks, but I am also thinking about long time for other things, eg jquery (gasp!) best practice...

Comment: It depends... Do you want to edit all fields at a time(e.g one button to turn all fields into inputs) or one by one??

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz one by one

Comment: Then we have some constraints here... The user will be able to "cancel" the input in real time? (e.g., turn the input into a field without in fact edit) Will it be an ajax edit??

Comment: I am asking because i'm actually facing the same problem and the only solution i were able to found is to hide an input field positioned exactly in the same place as the field and switch visibility between then on click event... The problem is that, using jquery replace to change a td into a div and vice versa will detach the event, so that the user will only be able to change each field into input one time=

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz - Use I would use hidden inline elements. Doing that isn't my problem, it's how to structure the code, where to put functions...

Answer (score 1):

You could write a little jQuery plugin to do it:

```
//tableEditor.js
;(function($){
    $.fn.tableEditor = function(settings) {
        var defaults = {stuff: 1, etc: true};
        settings = $.extend(defaults, settings || {});

        //using "on" so we wouldn't have to use multiple handlers for each link
        this.on('click', '.delete-item', function() { 
            e.preventDefault();
            var this_row = $(this).closest('tr');
            // do stuff
        });

        this.on('click', '.edit-item', function() { 
            e.preventDefault();
            var this_row = $(this).closest('tr');
            // do stuff
        });

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then call it like :

```
//main.js
$(function() { 
    $('#table').tableEditor({etc: false}); 
});
```

Comment: I edited it to show how to get the current row.

Answer (score 0):

you could do :

**Edit** : For dynamically added rows, use `.on()` in its delegated form :

```
$("#myTable").on("click", "td", function (event) {
    var thisID = $(this).siblings("td").eq(0).text(); // get ID of clicked row
    switch (event.target.className) {
        case "delete":
            //delete              
            alert("delete this ID = " + thisID);
            break;
        case "edit":
            // edit
            alert("edit this ID = " + thisID);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}); // on click
```

You still need to add a *class* to each clickable `td`

See NEW **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vn2ch/)** that includes a way to add rows.

**NOTE**: `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

Comment: Hi, couple of things, why use .on and not .click? Now if I want to add a function for calculating the total (price * quantity) and update the column, where would that code go? Don't write the code... writing it's not my problem it's how to structure it... a class? a plugin?

Comment: He used `.on` because the the rows should be added dynamically, using `.click` would only assign to the rows that existed when you called it.

Comment: @Wizzard : `.click()` is a shortcut of `.on("click")` and shortcuts have to be processed to their form anyways. Second, what to render after the click goes in the specific `case` wrapper.

Comment: Actually, botn, .on or .click() doesn't apply to elements added dynamically after DOM is loaded, @OneOfOne

Comment: @OneOfOne : not necessarily, in my code the `on` method is not in its delegated form, in that case it has to be `$("tr").on("click", "td", function (event) {`

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz : you are right, I edited my answer

Comment: @JFK I misread your code, but you should've used it in a dynamic way since the rows will be added later as far as I can tell.

Comment: @OneOfOne : my answer has been edited ;)